# Align bootstrap 4 columns in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to align my columns and rows to same height and same position. I managed it in desktop view but now I have problems in mobile view.

I attached 3 images, the first is the correct desktop view. Second is the mobile view and the third is the correct mobile view I want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Skp8.jpg

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-start">
        <div class="col-md">
            <h2>Környezetvédelem</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <h2>Történetünk</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <h2>Kapcsolat</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md ">
            <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/kornyezetvedelem.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/tortenetunk.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/kapcsolat.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to keep the correct lines in desktop view, even when the title takes two line but at the same time I want the correct order in mobile view.

Comment: Please check the below snippet. I have tweaked and updated  your code

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for posting a question and welcome to SO.  Please don't post links to other pages.  If you want to post the image comparison, just put it in your own post.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make two separate rows, instead use one row.Below your heading add the image that you want to display. Hope this works for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-start">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Környezetvédelem</h2>
        <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/kornyezetvedelem.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Történetünk</h2>
        <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/tortenetunk.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Kapcsolat</h2>
        <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/kapcsolat.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this solution.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Környezetvédelem</h2>
        <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/kornyezetvedelem.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Történetünk</h2>
        <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/tortenetunk.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Kapcsolat</h2>
        <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/kapcsolat.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-start">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h2>Környezetvédelem</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h2>Történetünk</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h2>Kapcsolat</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/kornyezetvedelem.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/tortenetunk.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <img class="img-fluid indep-sub-image" src="img/indep-menu/kapcsolat.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```